# Sourcecode in the url

Tags: html, url

normally you go on a website and by right click you can choose to see the source code. Or you just use firebug and select an element you want to analyse. Is it possible to write the source code in the URL so that it wouldn't be shown by right click + choosing or selecting an element?

I'm asking because I've already seen this phenomenon once by using an iphone simulator in safari.

Any ideas or hints what I'm exactly looking for? Your help would be great.

Edit: Based on wrong information. You can see the sourcecode by rightclicking. But the url still contains all information about the site. I'll get back to you as soon as I got more information to write them down clearly. Sorry for all the confusion.

Edit: This is the code in the url containing information about the site.

data:text/html;charset=utf-8;base64,PCFET0NUWVBFIGh0bWw%2BDQo8aHRtbCBtYW5pZmVzdD0naHR0cDovL25vdm93ZWIubWZ1c2UuY29tL3dlYmFwcC9TcG9ydGluZ2JldC9wb3J0YWwvc3BvcnRpbmdiZXRQb3J0YWwubWFuaWZlc3QnPg0KPGhlYWQ%2BPHRpdGxlPlNwb3J0aW5nYmV0PC90aXRsZT4NCiAgICA8bWV0YSBodHRwLWVxdWl2PSdjb250ZW50LXR5cGUnIGNvbnRlbnQ9J3RleHQvaHRtbDsgY2hhcnNldD11dGYtOCc%2BDQoJPG1ldGEgbmFtZT0ndmlld3BvcnQnIGNvbnRlbnQ9J21heGltdW0tc2NhbGU9MSwgd2lkdGg9ZGV2aWNlLXdpZHRoLCBoZWlnaHQ9ZGV2aWNlLWhlaWdodCwgdXNlci1zY2FsYWJsZT1ubywgbWluaW11bS1zY2FsZT0xLjAnPg0KICAgIDxtZXRhIG5hbWU9J2FwcGxlLW1vYmlsZS13ZWItYXBwLWNhcGFibGUnIGNvbnRlbnQ9J1lFUyc%2BDQogICAgPG1ldGEgbmFtZT0nYXBwbGUtbW9iaWxlLXdlYi1hcHAtc3RhdHVzLWJhci1zdHlsZScgY29udGVudD0nYmxhY2snPg0KICAgIDxzY3JpcHQgdHlwZT0ndGV4dC9qYXZhc2NyaXB0JyBsYW5ndWFnZT0namF2YXNjcmlwdCc%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%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%2BPC9zY3JpcHQ%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%2BPC9zY3JpcHQ%2BDQogICAgPHNjcmlwdCB0eXBlPSd0ZXh0L2phdmFzY3JpcHQnIHNyYz0naHR0cDovL25vdm93ZWIubWZ1c2UuY29tL3dlYmFwcC9TcG9ydGluZ2JldC9wb3J0YWwvUGFydHMvQnV0dG9uSGFuZGxlci5qcycgY2hhcnNldD0ndXRmLTgnPjwvc2NyaXB0Pg0KICAgIDxzY3JpcHQgdHlwZT0ndGV4dC9qYXZhc2NyaXB0JyBzcmM9J2h0dHA6Ly9ub3Zvd2ViLm1mdXNlLmNvbS93ZWJhcHAvU3BvcnRpbmdiZXQvcG9ydGFsL1BhcnRzL1RyYW5zaXRpb25zLmpzJyBjaGFyc2V0PSd1dGYtOCc%2BPC9zY3JpcHQ%2BDQogICAgPHNjcmlwdCB0eXBlPSd0ZXh0L2phdmFzY3JpcHQnIHNyYz0naHR0cDovL25vdm93ZWIubWZ1c2UuY29tL3dlYmFwcC9TcG9ydGluZ2JldC9wb3J0YWwvUGFydHMvU3RhY2tMYXlvdXQuanMnIGNoYXJzZXQ9J3V0Zi04Jz48L3NjcmlwdD4NCjwvaGVhZD4NCjxib2R5IG9uTG9hZD0nbG9hZCgpOyc%2BDQogICAgPGRpdiBpZD0nc3RhY2tMYXlvdXQnPjxkaXYgaWQ9J3NlbGVjdGlvbi1wYWdlJz4NCiAgICAgICAgICAgIDxkaXYgaWQ9J2xhbmRpbmdwYWdlJz4NCiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICA8ZGl2IGlkPSdjZW50cmVUb3BCRyc%2BPC9kaXY%2BPGRpdiBpZD0nY2VudHJlQm90dG9tQkcnPjwvZGl2Pg0KICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIDxkaXYgaWQ9J2xvZ28nPjwvZGl2Pg0KICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIDxkaXYgaWQ9J2ljb24nPjwvZGl2Pg0KICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIDxkaXYgaWQ9J2Rpc3BhbHlib3gnPg0KICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICA8ZGl2IGlkPSd0ZXh0cDEnPjwvZGl2Pg0KICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICA8ZGl2IGlkPSd0ZXh0cDInPjwvZGl2Pg0KICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIDwvZGl2Pg0KICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIDxkaXYgY2xhc3M9J3ZpZXcyJyBpZD0naXBob25lJz48L2Rpdj4NCiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICA8ZGl2IGNsYXNzPSd2aWV3MicgaWQ9J2Nhc2lubyc%2BPC9kaXY%2BDQogICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgPGRpdiBpZD0nZGlzcGFseWJveDMnPg0KICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICA8ZGl2IGlkPSd0ZXh0cDUnPjwvZGl2Pg0KICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICA8ZGl2IGlkPSd0ZXh0cDYnPjwvZGl2Pg0KICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICA8ZGl2IGlkPSd0ZXh0cDcnPjwvZGl2Pg0KICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICA8ZGl2IGlkPSd0ZXh0cDgnPjwvZGl2Pg0KICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICA8ZGl2IGlkPSd0ZXh0cDknPjwvZGl2Pg0KICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICA8ZGl2IGlkPSd0ZXh0cDEwJz48L2Rpdj4NCiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgPGRpdiBpZD0ndGV4dHAxMSc%2BPC9kaXY%2BDQogICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIDxkaXYgaWQ9J3RleHRwMTInPjwvZGl2Pg0KICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICA8ZGl2IGlkPSd0ZXh0cDEzJz48L2Rpdj4NCiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICA8L2Rpdj4NCiAgICAgICAgICAgIDwvZGl2Pg0KICAgICAgICA8L2Rpdj48ZGl2IGlkPSdpbnN0YWxsLWFwcC1wYWdlJz4NCiAgICAgICAgICAgIDxkaXYgaWQ9J2luc3RhbGwnPg0KICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIDxkaXYgaWQ9J2NlbnRyZVRvcEJHMSc%2BPC9kaXY%2BPGRpdiBpZD0nY2VudHJlQm90dG9tQkcxJz48L2Rpdj4NCiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICA8ZGl2IGlkPSdkaXNwYWx5Ym94MSc%2BDQogICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIDxkaXYgaWQ9J3RleHRwMyc%2BPC9kaXY%2BDQogICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIDxkaXYgaWQ9J3RleHRwNCc%2BPC9kaXY%2BDQogICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgPC9kaXY%2BDQogICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgPGRpdiBpZD0naWNvbjEnPjwvZGl2Pg0KICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIDxkaXYgaWQ9J2xvZ28xJz48L2Rpdj4NCiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICA8ZGl2IGlkPSdidXR0b24yJz48L2Rpdj4NCiAgICAgICAgICAgIDwvZGl2Pg0KICAgICAgICA8L2Rpdj48L2Rpdj4NCjwvYm9keT4NCjwvaHRtbD4=

Comment: "Hiding"? Wouldn't the source still be seen by just copying the URL anyway?

Comment: not when the url is coded - guess it was the wrong thing to describe it

Comment: You mean something like disable the user from looking at the source of your web page? (the URL has nothing to do with that)

Comment: Well, using an iPhone and loading sportingbet.com, the url changes to a coded sourcecode. By looking at any element there is no sourcecode given. So it has to to sth with the url because all the information come from the url. The url calls the scripts etc.

Comment: @falli: what should prevent the user from decoding the url? you _can't_ hide your sourcecode, and every try to do this will just annoy the users (who wants to send a link of a nice site to a friend if the url is 1000+ chracters long...)

Comment: @oezi - well, this site was made for iphone. iphone uses safari. by using safari and an agent simulating the use of an iphone i just couldnt see any sourcecode because the code was somewhere coded in the url. Just wanted to know how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're referring to is the data URI scheme, which allows base64 encoded data to be included locally (within a request), where normally http/etc URLs are used to initiate new requests.

> The data URI scheme is a URI scheme
>   that provides a way to include data
>   in-line in web pages as if they were
>   external resources. It tends to be
>   simpler than other inclusion methods,
>   such as MIME with cid or mid URIs.

Read the Wikipedia page for more details: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme

Answer (score 9):

No, it's not possible to hide a website's source code. The reason for that is simply that the *browser* needs that code to display the website, so whenever you see a website, you'll always be able to see as much code as is needed to make the website look like that.

You *can* mangle the code a bit, but as you have said yourself, things like Firebug are able to display the *current state* of a website, so you'll also be able to see the correct code.

#### edit

Just a note: Just because Safari with an iPhone user agent isn't able to display the source code, it doesn't mean that the code is not there or somehow encrypted into the URL. If you can see the website, the code is there.

I guess it's a bug (or a feature?) that Safari isn't able to display it in iPhone mode (maybe because the iPhone itself isn't able to display the code either).

#### edit 2

Okay, it indeed set the URL to the following for me:

> > data:text/html;charset=utf-8;base64,PGh0bWw%2BPGhlYWQ%2BPG1ldGEgbmFtZT0ndmlld3BvcnQnIGNvbnRlbnQ9J21heGltdW0tc2NhbGU9MSwgd2lkdGg9ZGV2aWNlLXdpZHRoLCB1c2VyLXNjYWxhYmxlPW5vLCBtaW5pbXVtLXNjYWxlPTEuMCc%2BPG1ldGEgbmFtZT0nYXBwbGUtbW9iaWxlLXdlYi1hcHAtY2FwYWJsZScgY29udGVudD0nWUVTJz48bWV0YSBuYW1lPSdhcHBsZS1tb2JpbGUtd2ViLWFwcC1zdGF0dXMtYmFyLXN0eWxlJyBjb250ZW50PSdibGFjayc%2BPE1FVEEgaHR0cC1lcXVpdj0ncmVmcmVzaCcgY29udGVudD0nMTtVUkw9aHR0cHM6Ly93ZWJhcHAubWZ1c2UuY29tL1Nwb3J0aW5nYmV0L2lwaG9uZS9pbmRleC1lbl9HQi5odG1sP2lkPTU4NjIwNEE2MEE0MDQ2MTUwMTM5MEZDQTFBQTdGNDFBJmxvY2FsZT1lbl9HQiZhZmZpbGlhdGVJRD0nPjwvaGVhZD48c3R5bGU%2BYm9keXtiYWNrZ3JvdW5kLWNvbG9yOiMwMDA7dGV4dC1hbGlnbjpjZW50ZXI7Y29sb3I6I0ZGRjtmb250LWZhbWlseTpBcmlhbCwgSGVsdmV0aWNhLCBzYW5zLXNlcmlmO2ZvbnQtc2l6ZToyMHB4O308L3N0eWxlPjxib2R5PjxwPmxvYWRpbmcuLi48L3A%2BPC9ib2R5PjwvaHRtbD4=

This however just encodes to a *loading & redirect page* that itself redirects to a different webpage with a special session-like parameter. I guess they didn't want to create real server side sessions for this and just put the parameter into the redirect page and encoded the whole junk using the `data:` URI to not create a custom page for it. This however does neither help the browser (in terms of speed or anything else) nor does it hide the source code, as you can just decode it again to see the original source code.

Comment: Hiding was the wrong word I guess. It's more like getting all information from the url. there is no source code on the site, but in the url.

Comment: Updated my answer. If the URL didn't change, then there obviously isn't more information in there than normal. This sounds like a simple bug of Safari to me..

Comment: Well, the url changes by loading the site.

Comment: @Faili, what do you mean by src code in URL? URLs are limited and if anyway  that site managed to compress it to that, ultimately browser is rendering it, so why wouldn't firebug or tool like that will see the DOM

Comment: @Faili, if it was possible that site would do that trick in other browser, can you show which one?

Comment: If the URL changed, the congratulations, you have successfully tested the intertubes, and it it still working.

Comment: @Faili: I don't have a Safari here, so can you post a screenshot or just paste the URL here? I *guess* that you are just seeing some user agent redirect to a mobile site.

Comment: Well, this site is just made for iPhone(safari) as far as I can see. By using FF, Chrome, etc. and a simulator following message apperas: Unfortunately, you have come to this page in error. The Sportingbet Webapp is not designed to be used in a browser.

Comment: I don't want to push my luck. But have you got an idea of where to start to reproduce it? I'd like to make a try but am not familiar with this.

Comment: *Why* do you want to reproduce that? Why do you think it will be of any help for you, and why do you expect any benefits of it?

Answer (score 1):

i don't know what you're trying to achive, but if you want to hide the source code because of "anybody can steal my code": that isn't possible. the sourcecode has to get to the browser in any way, so the browser can display it - and if the code is on the client-machine (in the browser) there will always be a possibility to grab it.

Comment: Well, I used an iphone simulator in safari. I know that it works with an iphone the same way. By choosing sportingbet.com with iphone, etc. the url changes during loading the site. After the site is loaded there is no way to choose any element from the sourcecode because the sourcecode is in the url how it seems - coded. I don't know how it works. maybe there's a misunderstanding.

Comment: mate, have you considered that you can't view source on an iphone itself?

Comment: @ Jason - Maybe not. What is with a simulator? Would it work the same way?

Answer (score 0):

Even if you restrict right clicking, or viewing the source, it is impossible to hide it from everybody. Also, placing it in the URL would be bad, very bad (I can't even imagine it).

Comment: If it's in the URL, you can see it anyway?

Comment: Could that have been a Flash/Silverlight application?

Comment: Can you provide a link? I'd like to see this for myself.

Comment: Also, the only way I can think to do something like this would be to have a browser built to do it (or a plugin), but it will still be sent over the tubes in plaintext (unless you're using HTTPS), so a smart user could sniff it anyway.

Comment: @ teedyay : iPhone or userAgent -> sportingbet.com

Comment: I can get any site's HTML source code by fetching the page from a Perl script, and save it into a text file. Even if it's restricted by using javascript.

Comment: @SWeko - have you got a link?

Comment: *“you have to use safari”* gives you a good hint that there might be some problem with Safari here…

Comment: I don't think it's a problem or bug because the url changes by loading the site. It also sees whether you are using a browser or not. It is really made for the iPhone in safari. Thought it could be to optimize the speed of the site. And coding the whole source code to 64bit could be helpful. Just a thought.

Answer (score 0):

the html is needed for the browser to render the UI. You can't hide it.
You could compress and obfuscate the javascript though, to make it difficult to read and understand. But that's evil :)

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer has a character limit of 2048 characters, so you would have to compress the content and pray it will fit in the url after it's been base64 encoded. Then you can use javascript to decode it. It will also be extremely difficult to update your pages or allow for bookmarking. It could also result in users exploiting the system.

Chances are nobody will want your sauce code anyway, and if they did, it wouldn't affect you one little bit. Facebook shows it's sauce, I don't see it's popularity dropping. So just stick with serving your pages the normal way.

Answer (score 0):

**1.** The length of an URL is limited, so that you couldn't write a whole page into it even if it were possible.

**2.** Once a thing has been displayed at a client machine the code cannot be protected.
(well, using javascript right-click disabling could repell a few noobs, but it is still fairly easy to grab the code)